# How to use cocoapods by programmatically (Ruby code call cocoapods API)

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

I want to call cocoapods API **pod update** by Ruby. I don't want to call it by **Command Line**, So how to do?

If use **system("pod update")**, How to get result? I want to know if it's successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `system`

```
system("pod update")
```

ref: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW, do you know how to get the result from this command? I want to know if success or not for **pod update**